# Load big size images as thumb

Tags: php, laravel, image, thumbnails

Hi I'm working with project that upload images as attachment everything working cool except that when I upload image from mobile its like 3 or 4 MB size, so when I view the images page took lots of time to load.
this is my example :
[image]

Now when someone click on theses images it will redirect to full image size in blank page, now is there anyway to load images as thumb 50*50 from the original size thanks

Comment: You need to create resized versions of the images which you use when you want to show the smaller images. You can either do that when the user uploads an image or "on demand" when it's fetched (using something like [Glide](https://github.com/thephpleague/glide) or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are saving these images in the storage, you need to also on the fly create thumbnails for  the same. And then use those when you need.

There are awesome packages available for the same of which  [intervention](http://image.intervention.io/) is the best one as per my opinion.

When  you use this package,  you can simply do :

```
// Make thumbnail of existing image : 

$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->resize(50, 50)->insert('public/foo50x50.png');

// Create thumbnail on the fly for uploaded images from fomr request

$image = $request->file('image');

$thumbnail = Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(50, 50)->save($destinationPath.'/'.$fileThumbnailName);

$image->move($destinationPath, $filaName);
```